# All Joint Angle values not converging to desired set point (I am using Roy Featherstone's Spatial Toolbox)

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, dynamics, simulation, simulator

I need the robot joint angles to become the same as given (desired) joint angles. The kinematics and dynamics (used Spatial Toolbox) are correct and the motor models are realistic too. But out of 3 joint angles, only one is converging at the desired set point, while the other ones are 'converging' at a random point.

I have tried tuning the 'PD controllers', 'PI controllers' as well as the 'gain' but only the 1st value converges. I am unable to understand the reason behind it. Kindly check the code and suggest if any improvement is needed.

Simulink model:
[image: Simulink model]

Joint angles: current and desired:
[image]

Simulink model, robot model and motor parameters are given here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1lgSdFRVsHGTVJ5ZWhURG05ZTg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I saw this as I was checking emails. Just got off a very long international flight so my answer below may not be super coherent. tl;dr - You're not *integrating* your reference error anywhere and so there's nothing that would drive your reference error to zero.

The Simulink model is confusing to me. What are your units? I think it would be helpful to me (and you!) if you labeled or subdiagrammed this to show what each portion is doing.

The thing that's confusing for me is that feedback systems will typically operate on a feedback *error*, which is `reference - feedback`. The reference *error* is then modified and that's what drives the response - a PID controller is trying to drive the reference error to zero.

It looks like you've got a `Jacobian*Force` term to generate some a torque signal, which seems okay because the Jacobian lets you relate an end effector's force to the joint forces.

The way that I would expect you would be using it, the way you have the outputs done, is that you're going to use the current pose of the arm and provide a desired end effector force vector, and you're going to output the joint torques.

You've got the output `Thm`, but then it's not `reference - feedback` to try to drive the motor torques to that value. You've got instead a "Desired torque" vector, so you've got `reference - other reference`.

Then you've got a set of PD controllers, but there's no plant/dynamics involved directly after those controllers and so it's not clear to me what they're controlling. What are the input/output units? Are you doing PD control to accept a torque *reference error* and generate a terminal voltage to drive the motor?

But if that *is* what you're doing, that summing junction between the PD controllers and PI controllers doesn't make sense to me, because the input on the negative junction is the output of `3DOF Robot` and/or the motor PI control block. That same output though also gets summed with the `Thm` torque output of the Jacobian function.

Basically your Jacobian is outputting a torque, which seems okay but then, assuming you're using the same units on both sides of your summing junctions, the output of Motor PI is torque and the output of PD controllers is torque and the output of Reference Torque is torque.

So you've got a reference torque, the Jacobian `Thm`, and you're building a controller(s) to do something with that reference, but then you skip to the end of your cascaded controllers and just add that `Thm` signal in there. What is it that the other controllers are doing then if you're going to throw the `Thm` signal in at the end?

In any event, the output of that last summing junction looks like a torque, which then makes sense to go into the next section, which I'm assuming is `FDab` or similar - takes inputs of `q`, `qd`, and `tau`, and you've got `q` and `qd` fed back from the integrators and what I'm assuming is `tau` out of that summing junction.

So then it goes from there into a forward dynamics, and then this is where your real `reference - feedback` is going on, except you've got it as `feedback - reference`, which ultimately doesn't matter because it's just a gain of `-1`, but anyways **this** is where your joint angle controller should go because *this* is the *only place* in your code that you seem to be comparing a reference (`Desired joint angles` vector) to a feedback (integrated dynamics simulation), but even here you're not comparing joint angles, you're comparing the output of *forward kinematics*, which would imply you're only looking at the end effector.

Looking a little harder at it, your forward kinematics output a 3x1 vector, which would only cover x/y/z *or* roll/pitch/yaw of the end effector; you don't have something like a quaternion + x/y/z for a 7x1 vector.

Finally, it would seem at a glance that you have something like a joint or end effector controller in that section of your code, but that block is a triangle, so it's just a gain. It's a gain acting on a reference error, so it's a *proportional* gain if you look at that like a PID controller. There's no integral term, so it's as though your integral gain is set to zero and you're never able to drive steady state error to zero.

Comment: This is an exoskeleton model. I need the human torque to be zero (desired Torque) and need all the torque to be provided by motors only. PD controllers drive the error faster which is used to control joint motors. Dynamics are converting tau (motor output+desired human torque) to joint angles. The difference between current and desired end-effector positions is used to get force: F=k*x and `Thm` is computed. It is being added to motor output because both of these torques are acting on exoskeleton. This `Thm` needs to be zero as it is provided by human.

Comment: @Capri - you're describing two different goals: driving the end effector to a desired position and driving human torque to zero. What if these two goals are different? Imo, you should have one reference input, zero torque, and one feedback, human torque. Your torque error is then whatever nonzero torque the person is applying and your controllers will drive motor torque (and thus adjust the exoskeleton) until human torque matches your reference torque, i.e., zero.

Comment: Also, FYI, you should check out compliant control, because I think that's essentially what you're going for here.

Comment: I am using intention-based control. Practically, I will use a force sensor to measure current force 'Fhm' to reach to a position. But for simulation, I am computing it through the 'gain of current-minus-desired joint angles'. Is this method correct?

Comment: @Capri - it sounds like you're intending to use force feedback, but you're simulating with position references. If you're not simulating the problem you're trying to solve then I'm not sure what the point of the simulation is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it now. I will look through the force feedback part to make the problem as close to experiment as possible.